# What would be the quickest way to create a long form on iOS/iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm fairly new to the world of Objective-C and iOS development (this is my first iphone app), and i have a background in c#/java dev.

My employer wants an iphone app for one of our sites. In it, there's supposed to be a form that has about 50 fields in it and can be broken up into 3 different sections if needed.

What would be the best way to go about handling this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a UITextField for each of the fields.

Then I would add those as subviews of 3 UIViews that will represent the 3 sections you mentioned (breaking up the UITextFields into each view as necessary).

Then I would create a UIScrollView and add each of these UIViews as subviews (stacking them by position; ie bottom of first is touching top of second) .

This will allow you to scroll through the UIViews if the page is too long (50 fields will most likely not fit on an iPhone screen).

For more info:

UIView - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

UIScrollView - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

UITextField - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Answer (score -1):

There are some tutorials out there for this. Basically, I would create all appropriate fields or form criteria, and embed them in a srollview. You select all the fields and click editor>embed in>scrollview.

You then need to setup the field to scroll into view when it is clicked. This can be found in tutorials.

You then need to setup a function to dismiss the keyboard if a user clicks off the field. Again this can be found on tutorials.

If you need anymore help please comment. My background is java too and have just started learning Obj-c and swift.